# Modifying Eclipse EMF Editor New Child menu without changing providers

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf

I am having a problem modifying EMF's automatically created "New Child" menu to create submenus for certain kinds of items. I found that, by default, the pipe symbol is used as a separator, so a child object with the name `Hamburger | Megaplusbig` results in a `Hamburger` submenu appearing. [This page](http://blog.mattsch.com/2013/05/02/modifying-the-new-child-sub-menu-items-in-emf/) seems to suggest that overriding `getCreateChildText()` in the relevant item provider is a good option.

What I want is for certain types of model items to appear in a submenu, and to achieve this I'd just make sure that `MySubmenu |` gets prepended to the name. My problem is that classes for the model which I'm editing in Eclipse are in a separate Jar file that I can't (or rather really shouldn't) modify.

And I have not had much luck trying to achieve this in another way. My other attempt was extending `BasicModelEditActionProvider` and overriding its `fillContextMenu()` and `updateActions()` methods. The latter does create submenus through another call to `BasicActionProvider.extractSubmenuActions()`, which I again could override, but by then the information about my model objects is lost in the abstraction. That method works on `IAction` lists and even if I cast the action to `StaticSelectionCommandAction` (which it always is), the `command` field has no public getter, and it's only through fields of `command` that I see the actual EMF EObject somewhere.

I'm looking for a not-too-ugly solution that doesn't involve modifying the item providers in the Jar file, unless I really have to do it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end, the only solution that worked is unfortunately a hack. I went with overriding `extractSubmenuActions()` in my `BasicModelEditActionProvider`, changing it to give me the submenus I wanted. The ugly part is finding the EMF object to-be-added, for which I unfortunately used reflection to forcefully read the protected `command` field of the normally abstracted `IAction`.

This forcefully breaks the encapsulation but due to external constraints on my code, I was unable to modify the item providers of the model. The reflective solution is not pretty, but works perfectly.